# Система PUSH-уведомлений на IOS|ANDROID

Tags: php, laravel, push-уведомления, очередь, laravel-5.6

коллеги. Есть задача реализации на сервере с Laravel 5.6 системы уведомлений для пользователей API (IOS - APNS\FCM , Android - FCM).

Сейчас делаю так:

С админки создаю уведомление, оно добавляется в базу, а далее создается очередь, которая делает выборку с бд пользователей ANDROID и IOS, разбивает их по чанкам (по 5000), и создает еще очередь для каждого чанка, которая уже отправляет пачкой на FCM|APNS .

Вопрос в том, правильно ли я это делаю? А если нет, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно. Спасибо =)

Comment: Работает - не трож =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков просто хотелось бы лучшие решения применять для текущей и дальнейшей разработки

Comment: Преждевременная оптимизация - не всегда хорошо, если стабильно работает, удовлетворяет производительность - не нужно лезть.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков просто не хотелось бы в дальнейшем во всех поддержуемых проектах переписывать (как сейчас, т.к. до этого решение было похуже, и уже с 100к пользователями не справлялось).